# blender can't lock emitter, like 3dsmax

Tags: particles

My problem is that the emitted particles don't lock with object (in animate modifier wave, solidify, lattice etc), 
[image]

in frame 30 particle get wind and turbulance

Comment: do you mean you want the particles to stick to the emitter?

Comment: yes, particles stick to object

Comment: so you should try to put the Velocity > Normal at 0, and Field Weight > Gravity at 0, but if you don't need them to fall, maybe use Hair rather than Emitter?

Comment: i mean, how to make particle stick to emitter at 0 to 29 and get wind and turbulence at frame 30

Comment: you can insert keyframes on any value, for example at frame 29 give Gravity a value of 0, insert a keyframe (move over the value and press i), at frame 30 give it a value of 1 and insert a keyframe. To create wind or turbulence, create (shift A) a Force Field and same thing you can play with its intensity with some keyframes.

Comment: your answer is my problem now... the particles not sticky

Comment: they will be if you set the values and insert keyframes properly  ;)